# checking a sequence for proper order in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am looking for a way to "detect" if a sequence of ordered objects turns out of order.

I try to explain it with an simplified example:

I am using an IEnumerable of TourStop which is defined as this:

```
class TourStop 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Sorting {get;set;}
    public string LocationTitle {get;set;}
    public bool Done {get;set;}
}
```

As my piece of software is used by humans, it's possible that a user set the done property in a random order which would lead to gaps in the "processing order". And that's what I want to extract from the collection: "Give me all TourStops which are not done and seem to be out of order".

And now the tricky part! Here are some examples as a simple boolean array:

```
[1,1,1,0,0,0] // the algorithm should return nothing. The first three elements are processed in correct order and the rest of them may not be processed yet
[0,1,1,0,0,0] // here the algorithm should return only the first element
[1,0,0,1,1,0] // here the algorithm should return only the 2nd and 3rd element
```

Any ideas how to build such a query?

Comment: I think you need to re-think your design.  This sounds very brittle. You should look at how to stop people making the mistake in the first place.

Comment: What do you expect from this `[1,0,1,0,1,0]`? 2nd and 4th?

Comment: Create an empty list. Loop the input. If you find a `0` then *start* appending to the list (use a flag). If you find a `1` immediately return the list. after the loop, return `null` (or empty list) as it cannot get this far without being a valid order

Comment: So basically you're searching for a way to find the first range of 0s in the array that has 1 both as pre- and suffix?

Comment: So basically you don't want to know **if** they are out of order, but which ones. You want to find items that are not done but occur before the last done element?

Comment: I agree with Darren. You could use IComparable :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx. Make it the business of each object to know whether or not it's less than another.

Comment: How do you know if it's the "0" element that is out of order? Example: `[1,1,0,1,0,0]` either the 3rd or 4th could be wrong.

Comment: `list.Reverse().SkipWhile(x => !x.Done).Where(x => !x.Done);`  and add another `Reverse` to the end if the order matters at this point.

Comment: Or you can just order by "done" and then by "sorting" if i understand you correctly. Or use a sorted collection. But why is it a problem to begin with?

Comment: @Roma You saved my Day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have `List` of `TourStop`. So, you need to find all `"0"` before last `"1"`:

```
List<TourStop> tourStops = new List<TourStop>();

// initialize list with your values

int index = tourStops.FindLastIndex((t) => t.Done);

List<TourStop> outOfOrder = null;

if (index > 0)
{
    outOfOrder = tourStops.Where((el) => !el.Done && tourStops.LastIndexOf(el) < index).ToList();
}
```

After that you can check if `outOfOrder == null`.

If so, there are not out of order elements.

If not, `outOfOrder` will contain all out of order elements.

Also, you can try query which **@juharr** commented.